# Sort a groupby plot bar chart

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, seaborn, bar-chart

I have a Pandas `DataFrame`, and I `groupby` a column, call `.size` and then call `.plot.bar`

I want to reorder the bars by some columns in the original dataframe, but passing them in `sort_columns` for `bar()` is not working:

```
nodes.groupby("Name").size().plot.bar(sort_columns="Class")
```

Presorting the columns in the dataframe also has no effect - how can you order the columns in a Pandas bar chart?

Comment: I get an `AttributeError` when I try to run the `nodes.groupby...` line of code. Please provide a [working example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)..

Comment: The grouped & aggregated `DataFrame` will have fewer rows than the original one (if there was anything to group). How do you plan on sorting the reduced second `DataFrame` by columns of the larger source with more entries?

Comment: Stefan, the grouped entries columns I want to sort on should be homogenous (for each group, all entries should be the same). Im grouping by name, and class is specific to each name.

Comment: Can you give a cut-n-pastable example of the error?

Answer (score 2):

I have created a random dataframe to help visualize the data.

```
#creating random data

data = {'a' : np.random.randint(0, 10, size = 10),
        'b' : np.random.randint(0, 10, size = 10),
        'c' : np.random.randint(0, 10, size = 10),
        'd' : np.random.randint(0, 10, size = 10),
        'e' : np.random.randint(0, 10, size = 10)}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

# Custom sorting of columns
df.iloc[0][['a', 'c', 'd', 'b', 'e']].T.plot.bar()
```

[[image: Plot 1]]

```
# Sorting columns in acsending or decending order
df.iloc[0].sort_values(ascending = False).T.plot.bar()
```

[[image: Plot 2]]

Note: The parameter column_sort sorts the columns by their names not their values.